# C# Conversion from VB6 - Recordset

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, ado, recordset

I'm wanting to convert the line to C# from VB6 and am having quite the difficulty doing so.

VB6 Code:

```
txtFields(4).Text = rsGroup.Fields(0).Value + 1
```

C#: (what I have so far)

```
txtFields4.Text = (rsGroup.Fields[0].Value) +1);
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What is the difficulty in the specific example?

Comment: Your C# example has an extra parenthesis at the end. Also your VB code has an array of text fields and you're accessing the text field at index 4 while your c# has one text field named txtField4. Was that intentional? I'm curious, what is the C# type for the object rsGroup?

Comment: What type is 'Value'? Are you trying to add an integer to a string, or are you adding 2 integers and putting them into a string property?

Answer (score 1):

@jdurman,

An example of retrieving data using a DataSet is:

```
public DataSet GetDate(string SqlString)
{
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING GOES HERE");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlString, sqlConn);
adapter.Fill(ds);

return ds;

}

public void LoopThroughDataExample(DataSet ds)
{
foreach(DataTable dt in ds)
{
foreach(DataRow dr in dt)
{
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Value is: {0}", dr["DBColumnName"])); // Replace DBColumnName with the name of columns in the Database Table that you want to Extract.
}
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help there Robbie, that's great! I have one main concern with this, the database I'm using this program for is not a mainstream one (SQL/MSAccess etc) it is HABITAT (http://www.ponge.com/telechargements/habitat.pdf) - I think I'm going to try as far as I can with the conversion then learn how I can use the habitat .dll's to get access to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a RecordSet and Use a DataSet instead.
you can use the System.Data.SqlClient namespace to be able to access Databases and then you can bind controls from your DataSet, makes life alot easier, and also i would avoid doing straight copying of code from VB6. There is alot of new thing in the world of C# that you would never of had the option of using in VB6 prior.

Comment: Hi Robbie, I'm considering using the Dataset solution. I'll look into it - I guess the real difficulty here is that I have no C# knowledge.... Only java - my manager has asked me to do a conversion of an old database comparison tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtFields[4].Text = rsGroup.Fields[0].Value + 1;
```

Comment: Hi enamrik, the C# type for rsGroup is a ADODB.Recordset.